# Implication of "you have to realize"

Tags: connotations

Is the phrase neutral, like "you need to know", or it has some negative connotations?

Comment: "You need to know" and "you have to realize" are different phrases, with different connotations. Are you asking about both of them?

Comment: No, only about 'you have to realize'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context, context, context.

If you suspect that your hearer does not know *X*, *You have to realize X* is informative: it means "I tell you X because it is necessary that you know it*. In this case, it is more or less equivalent to *You need to realize/know X*.

> To understand why he is doing it that way you have to realize that he has very little training.

If you suspect that your hearer *does* know *X*, *You have to realize X* is a reproach: it means *Surely you know X—why are you ignoring it!*.

> Why are you just standing there? You have to realize that a horde of angry orcs is about to descend on us!

Note that *You need to* will not bear this meaning.

Comment: I think there something a bit odd about telling someone it's necessary that they *realize* something (as opposed to simply saying you would be surprised if they didn't already know it), because realization isn't really a voluntary activity. In a similar vein, whereas I'm happy with *I'm reading this book to understand [quantum physics, why God created wasps, etc.]*, it just doesn't seem quite right to replace *understand* with *realize* there. I feel that if you're actively doing something in this general area, you must either be seeking to *understand* or to *appreciate*, not *realize*.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning that *You **must** know/realise X* is a (probably more common) alternative for your second sense above.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Or *You('ve) gotta*

Comment: Ah, right! I'm not sure if it's any different to the AmE ear, but to *me* at least, *You ('ve) gotta know your wife's been cheating on you* can only mean that in the opinion of the speaker it's not possible that you don't know. If it were a "performative" statement (speaker thinks it's *necessary* that you know something you don't already, so he's actually *telling* you right now), I'd have to articulate it more fully as *You have **got** to know your wife's been cheating on you* (but I'd probably say *You **need** to know...* anyway).